# Nested while loop only runs once

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use this script to add text to every file in a folder. It is working, but only on the first file in the folder. The for statement seems to be working because it is giving an accurate count of the files in the folder, but only modifying the first file. I feel like I am missing something stupid here.

```
   $fullPath = "M:\BHX\DrillTeqConversion"
   $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("M:\BHX\DrillteqConversion.txt")
   $lineNumberx = 25


   function get200Files($path) {
        $mprFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $path -include *.mpr -Recurse)
 
     if ($mprFiles -ne $NULL) {
         $mprFileCount = 0

       For ($i = 0; $i -lt $mprFiles.Length; $i++) {
         $mprFileCount += 1
         $thisFile = $mprFiles[$i]
              
         while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {

            $textToAdd =  $line
 
            $newLineToAdd =  "`n" 

                 $fileContent = Get-Content $thisFile
                 $fileContent[$lineNumberx-1] += $newLineToAdd
         

                 $fileContent[$lineNumberx-1] += $textToAdd
                 $fileContent | set-Content $thisFile


            $lineNumberx = $lineNumberx + 1

         
          }
       }

       Write-Host ("A total of " + $mprFileCount + " files were converted.")
     }
   }

   get200Files $fullPath
```

Comment: In your For you want $mprFiles.Count vs .Length.

Comment: Still seems to only be modifying the first one

Comment: `[System.IO.File]::OpenText("M:\BHX\DrillteqConversion.txt")` with `ReadLine()` only allows reading through a file once. You need to reopen the file if you are going to use that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[System.IO.File]::OpenText("M:\BHX\DrillteqConversion.txt")` with `ReadLine()` only allows reading through a file once. So you cannot loop through the file endlessly without reopening it or using another strategy. Code samples below have been reduced for simplicity.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $mprFiles.Length; $i++) {
    # for loop code before while loop
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("M:\BHX\DrillteqConversion.txt")
    while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
        # while loop code
    }
    # After while loop but inside of For loop
    $reader.Dispose()
    $reader.Close()
}
```

---

You could make a new parameter for your function and pass that into `OpenText()` as well.

```
function get200Files($path,$FileToRead) {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $mprFiles.Length; $i++) {
        # for loop code before while loop
        $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($FileToRead)
        while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
            # while loop code
        }
        # After while loop but inside of For loop
        $reader.Dispose()
        $reader.Close()
    }
}

$fullPath = "M:\BHX\DrillTeqConversion"
$ReaderPath = "M:\BHX\DrillteqConversion.txt"
get200Files $fullPath $ReaderPath
```

Comment: I think the script could also potentially replace the whole ```while``` loop with a call to ```Get-Content "M:\BHX\DrillteqConversion.txt" -Raw``` and append that to reach file, rather than hand-crank appending one line at a time with ```$reader```. (Unless the file is *huuuuuuge*)

Comment: @mclayton Agreed. I don't like this extra complexity unless is it required for performance purposes.

Comment: Thank You! I got it by using your second example. The only issue I am having now is that it is copying the lines from the source file into the destination file in the wrong order (bottom to top if that makes sense)

Comment: @mclayton Files aren't large at all, and i'll take any advice to get this thing a little more stream lined